# jQuery scripts conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement two different, simple jquery codes on my website:

1. CookieCutter
2. jQuery animate function

After I added the cookiecuttr into the code, .animate stopped working.

I am a jquery beginner, therefore any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Here is cookiecuttr code (external file)

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery.cookieCuttr( 
{
cookieAnalytics: true,  
cookieAnalyticsMessage: 'cookiecuttr message' />',
cookieWhatAreTheyLink: 'cookies.htm',
cookieNotificationLocationBottom: true
}
);
});
```

and .animate that stopped working (in html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#phone_trigger").click(function () {
$("div#cta_nav").animate({
width: 'toggle'
});;
});
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have called noConflict() `$` does not refer to jQuery anymore, so use `jQuery` to refer to jQuery.

In the dom ready handler you will receive the jQuery instance as the first parameter, you can name it as `$` within the dom ready handler so that you will not have to use the longer `jQuery` form everytime

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#phone_trigger").click(function () {
        $("div#cta_nav").animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });
    });
});
```